# Pandas Dataframe - Finding Duplicates of One Column But Different in Another Column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe, for example, like this:

| idx | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a1 | b1 |
| 1 | a2 | b1 |
| 2 | a2 | b2 |
| 3 | a2 | b1 |
| 4 | a3 | b3 |
| 5 | a3 | b3 |
| 6 | a4 | b1 |

I want to find the duplicated values in Column A, but different values in Column B, and select all the indexes.

In above example, the results should be:

| idx | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a2 | b1 |
| 2 | a2 | b2 |
| 3 | a2 | b1 |

- Drop idx 0 and 6, the values in Column A are unique.
- Drop idx 4 and 5, because the values in Column B are the same.
- I want to keep both idx 1 and 3 in the results, although they are the same, but they have a different value in idx 2 (not all the same).

How can I achieve this goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use two [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) for [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
g = df.groupby('A')['B']

# is A duplicated and are the duplicates non-unique?
out = df[g.transform('count').gt(1) & g.transform('nunique').gt(1)]

# the non-unique condition is however implying the duplication of A
# we can simplify to:
out = df[df.groupby('A')['B'].transform('nunique').gt(1)]
```

Or, with [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
s = df.groupby('A')['B'].nunique()

out = df[df['A'].isin(s[s>1].index)]
```

Output:

```
   idx   A   B
1    1  a2  b1
2    2  a2  b2
3    3  a2  b1
```